# How To Cache Audio Files In Unity Android

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, audio

I’m developing an app in unity for android, not a game, and I want to download and cache my audio files so that the user can load them offline.

Comment: Could you please add some code, so we can help you, also I suggest you to store your downloaded audio files to a folder named **.FOLDERNAME** (add . before the folder name) this will make the folder invisible for the users

Comment: @MouaadAbdelghafourAITALI Thanks for your response, but I'm a beginner and I don't know how to download and cache audio.